# How to add a caption to a picture with an object in ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Good afternoon everyone!
There is a picture with a T-shirt in two versions - normal visibility and UV spectrum. You need to overlay the picture with the text on the football block so that the inscription repeats all the bends of the shirt using ImageMagick.

Tried like this:
 `convert ./tmp/tmpimage.jpg ./tmp/shirt_uv.png -fx p{u[0].w*v.r,u[0].h*v.g} tmp/shirt.png -compose HardLight -composite tmp/shirt.png -alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite ./tmp/out.png'`

this code only smears the inscription on the entire football block. Tell me how to write it correctly? I thik than my fx is not correct. Thank you!

Comment: Please post your images

Comment: Lookl like this http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/tshirt/index.php with Mario

Comment: Perhaps try that script in place of writing it from scratch.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the -fx expression?

Comment: Post your input images so we can see what you are using and trying to do.